# Does SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[expr,spec]] create a separate thread?

Tags: implementation-details, asynchronous-processing, scheduledtask

I don't quite understand how `SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[expr,spec]]` works.
We can create a background task, which can go without interfering with the main loop.

If I want to make asynchronous calculations in a way like it is done in JS using callbacks or promises, what should I use?

Is it necessary to implement something like an event-loop (similar to NodeJS)?

```
While[True,
(*check the stack of the events and call corresponding functions*)
];
```

if I have a lot of small events. I guess calling `SessionSubmit` at each callback will cost a lot.

PS: I am using wolframscript and a webserver running as `SocketListener`.

Comment: Look at "LocalSubmit"

Comment: Daniel, it looks like. LocalSubmit starts a new Kernel, but we can still create an infinite number of tasks using SessionSubmit, right?

Comment: That is right. LocalSubmit starts a new kernel, whereas SessionSubmit starts a new task in the current kernel. However, I doubt about an infinite number :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok. It learned that SessionSubmit acts like an interruption for the main loop (like in low level languages like C), as well as some other interruptions from the Socket objects and etc. Scheduled tasks work on timers which also fire an interruption and block the main loop.

Single thread, no surprises.

LocalSubmit acts in the same way as RunCommand but a bit
more advanced by starting a new kernel and connecting to it via sockets (wstp).